# SQL Assisgnment help - Obtaining age

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am someone learning SQL in my spare time and have just created an account to ask for some help on a tutorial i am trying. I am hoping someone can help me on this. 
below is the context of the scenario. Please can someone assist me. Once that is done, i have a part 2 to complete and once that is done I will post that here to check if all looks correct. Just a note i have attempted questions myself before posting:

**Scenario:**
 From the inpatient table which contains data from 2012 till today and
   has over a million records, perform the following actions (create
   subsets so we can query faster later on:

**Criteria**

- Find CHD patients from April 2012 – March 2013, the diagnoses can be 
  primary or secondary diagnoses.
- Find patients with disease ‘P11’    for April 2012 – March 2013 again
  the diagnoses can be primary or    secondary diagnoses
- Remove CHD patients who have disease ‘P11’ in    April 2012-March
  2013
- Find ‘P11’ Disease in April 2013 – March 2014
- Create Final Dataset with CHD Patients in April 2012-March 2013
  with P11 in Apr2013-Mar 2014
- Find Date of earliest diagnosis of    ‘P11’ in the cases during the
  defined time period, this would be    defined as index date
- Find Patients aged above 19 and alive on    index date

**My attempts**:

- Find CHD patients April 2012- March2013:

```
create table chd_patients201213 
as
select * 
from inpatient 
where enddate between '2012-04-01' and '2013-03-31' 
and ( ( left(Primary_diag, 3) in ( ‘CHD’ ) ) 
   or ( left(Secondary_diag, 3) in ( ‘CHD )
```

- Patients who have P11 for 2012-2013:

```
create table P11_patients201213 as 
select * from inpatient where disdate between '2012-04-01' and '2013-03-31' 
and ( left(primary_diag, 3) in (‘P11') or left(secondary_diag, 3) in (‘P11’) )
```

- Remove CHD patients diagnosed with P11 for 2012-2013

```
create table CHD_withoutp11 
as 
select * 
from chd_patients201213 
 where patientid not in ( select patientid from P11_patients201213 )
```

- Find ‘P11’ Disease in April 2013 – March 2014

```
create table P11_patients201314 as 
select * 
from inpatient 
where disdate between '2013-04-01' and '2014-03-31' 
and ( left(primary_diag, 3) in (‘P11') 
   or left(secondary_diag, 3) in (‘P11’) )
```

- Create Final Dataset with CHD Patients in April 2012-March 2013 with
  P11 in Apr2013-Mar 2014

```
create table chd_withp11_1314 
as 
select * 
from CHD_withoutp11 
where patientid in ( select hesid from P11_patients201314 )
```

- Find Date of earliest diagnosis of ‘P11’ in the cases during the
  defined time period, this would be defined as index date

```
create table chd_index 
as 
select patientid, min(disdate) as indexdate
from chd_withp11_1314 
group by patientid
```

- Find Patients aged above 19 and alive on index date *(I'm unsure of
  this but here is the steps I have done):

  *Find age of patients on index date*

```
create table chd_age 
as 
select t1.patientid, t1.endage as age, t1.dismeth, t2.indexdate
from chd_withp11_1314 t1 
   inner join chd_index t2 
           on t1.patientid=t2.patientid 
          and t1.disdate=t2.indexdate 
group by t1.hesid, t1.endage, t2.indexdate,t1.dismeth
```

*Patients aged above 19 and alive on index date*

```
create table chd_18andalive as 
select distinct (patientid),age,dismeth 
from chd_age 
where (age between 19 and 250 ) 
and dismeth not in ('dead')
```

Please can someone kindly assist me on the last bit where I have noted I am unsure of. Also, if at any stage you feel it can be improved to be made more efficient please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Kudos to you for trying to learn SQL, but your question is too broad at the moment.  Instead, just ask about a single query on which you are stuck and include sample data from the table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I only included the whole context so everyone can understand how I got to that stage. I hope that makes sense

Comment: Not sure is this is a copy and paste error but `‘`  or `’` are invalid in SQL. Use `'`

Answer (score 0):

Solving these questions for you would spoil the fun, but let me give you a few hints:

- Not all of these questions ask for `CREATE TABLE` statements. If the question is “*Find …*”, they are probably looking for a `SELECT` statement; “*Remove …*” asks for a `DELETE`, and I'm not sure what a “*final dataset*” is supposed to be, but maybe `CREATE TABLE ... AS` is correct.
- Instead of `WHERE x IN ('value')` you could use the more readable `WHERE x = 'value'`.

Comment: In the tutorial it did ask to create a sub table for each question as this will help query faster as the original dataset includes 1m+ records. 
Also, I need help in solving these questions as Im unsure and at this current stage it isn't "fun"

Comment: Also, postgresql doesnt allow me to use the = and therefore i end up using the in function

Comment: @healthiq: Postgres most  definitely allows you to use `=`, e.g. `where id = 42` or `where x = 'foobar'`

Comment: But if you want to learn SQL, how can you benefit from reading somebody else's answer? If the course you're making doesn't give you samples to study before it gives you an assignment, you should find a different course.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for that, will try use that next time

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe From somebody else answering I can see where I went wrong and what i need to focus on. It's not like I'm asking someone to do the work for me. I have put up my attempt and now asking for some assistance so I can get myself on the right track and improve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar so have a look on my post for ideas! Sorry that other users think they are doing the work for you and not assisting